# Camel AWS-SQS: Set visibilityTimeout dynamically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have a camel route defined roughly as follows:

```
from("aws-sqs://my-queue")
.process(myProcessor)
.to(myEndpoint);
```

However, `myProcessor` relies on an upstream service that sometimes becomes unavailable or returns a "pending" response, so the processor throws an exception and the exchange is left on the queue. Camel then polls and fails successively until the message is DLQed.

What I would like to do is configure `visibilityTimeout` dynamically to implement an exponential back-off until the upstream service is available again. So instead of `from("aws-sqs://my-queue?visibilityTimeout=30")`, I would register an exception handler in my route and inside of it, do something like:

```
sqsClient.setVisibilityTimeout(Math.pow(2 * visibilityTimeout));
```

Is this possible? And as a bonus, is it possible to configure the visibility timeout for a specific message id (eg. so it doesn't affect the visibility timeout of other messages)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change VisibilityTimeout for messages being processed.

From [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#changing-message-visibility-timeout):

> When you receive a message for a queue and begin to process it, the
>   visibility timeout for the queue may be insufficient (for example, you
>   might need to process and delete a message). You can shorten or extend
>   a message's visibility by specifying a new timeout value using the
>   ChangeMessageVisibility action.
>
> For example, if the timeout for a queue is 60 seconds, 15 seconds have
>   elapsed, and you send a ChangeMessageVisibility call with
>   VisibilityTimeout set to 10 seconds, the total timeout value will be
>   the elapsed time (15 seconds) plus the new timeout value (10 seconds),
>   a total of 25 seconds. Sending a call after 25 seconds will result in
>   an error.
>
> Note
>
> The new timeout period will take effect from the time you call
>   the ChangeMessageVisibility action. In addition, the new timeout
>   period will apply only to the particular receipt of the message. The
>   ChangeMessageVisibility action does not affect the timeout of later
>   receipts of the message   or later queues.

Comment: Can this be done within a camel route, or from the context or it requires the `SQSClient`?

Answer (score 0):

AWS SQS provides the flexibility to change the visibilityTimeout at message level (when processing the message) by calling "ChangeMessageVisibility" method.

However the current visibility timeout of the message can't be retrieved to perform your desired operation (Math.pow(2 * visibilityTimeout));

ChangeMessageVisibility method call:

```
sqsClient.ChangeMessageVisibility(myEndpoint, myMessage.getReceiptHandle(), 60);
```

The above code adds a visibilityTimeout of 60 seconds to the elapsing timeout of the message.

(i.e) If the message has default queue level visibilityTimeout of 30 seconds left, the above code adds 60 seconds to it and increases the message unavailability for other consumers to 90 seconds.

Comment: Above code will not add on original visibility time. In fact, it only adds up elapsed time + requested time. Example- initial visibility time set was 30 sec and after 10 seconds, you requested again to extend by 60 sec then 10 + 60 = 70 Sec. Not 90 Sec.